# c# StreamReader ReadLine() Keep Quotes

Tags: c#, networking

I have the following, and need to get the first line from the socket, but not have c# remove the quotes. I can't escape the quotes in the input as they come from a source I don't control.

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(socketStream);
string firstLine = sr.ReadLine();
```

Example Input Line: GET "/aaaadoe"

firstLine equals GET /aaaadoe and not GET "/aaaadoe".

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure the quotes are actually coming inside the socket payload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`StreamReader` does not remove quotes. Some ideas:

1. The quotes were not sent
2. Something else removed them
3. You are not looking at the right string, or misinterpreting the debugger display of it